# How can i do session handling in angularjs with javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session-cookies

> There are only two points in the application where the login should
>   appear:
>
> 1. When I am not logged in and I attempt to visit a page that requires login, e.g. my profile page.
> 2. When I attempt to make a request that requires a login, e.g. my session has expired whilst I’m attempting to post something.

Comment: You can search and use `$sessonStorage` or `$coockiesStorage` or `$localStorage` in angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use HtML5 $sessonStorage or $localStorage.

Example
--------
sessionStorage.setItem('id', userId);
sessionStorage.getItem('id');
```

Comment: is html 5 is compatible with all browsers?

Answer (score 1):

With angularJS :

- To save value : `$window.sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value')`
- To retreive value : $`scope.name = $window.sessionStorage.getItem('key')`

Here is a small example : 
http://jsfiddle.net/gioeleslfierro/s0pm6gcq/

I suggest you to use the angular way with $window. But if you want to do it by yourself its pretty similar ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)) :

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('key');

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```